# Execution Time Difference between two bit-wise differential execution

Tags: python-3.x, xor, encryption-symmetric

I found an interesting phenomenon, when I try to do symmetric encryption (Bit-wise XOR execution) for a figure with another random figure. The execution time is different between encryption and decryption, and the difference might be 4 to 6 times (encryption period: 1.2 sec, decryption period: 0.2 sec). The encryption execution cost more time than decryption. I'm so confuse why causes the difference. I have attached the code below.

```py
# Encryption Execution
start_time = time.time()
encrypted_figure = differential_fig(origin_img, input_random_img, 1)
end_time = time.time()
```

```py
# Decryption Execution
start_time = time.time()
decrypted_figure = differential_fig(encrypted_figure, input_random_img, 0)
end_time = time.time()
```

```py
# Called Function 
def element_xor(first_array, second_array):
    array_size = first_array.size
    output_array = np.zeros(array_size, dtype=np.int32)
    for e in range(array_size):
        output_array[e] = first_array[e] ^ second_array[e]
    return output_array

def sliding_window_differential(raw_array, random_array, raw_size, random_size, flag):
    indexes_list = []
    times = range(math.floor(raw_size / random_size))
    num_remain_elements = raw_size % random_size
    for j in times:
        start_index = j * random_size + num_remain_elements
        end_index = start_index + random_size
        indexes_list.append([start_index, end_index])
    iterative_index = [[0, random_size]] + indexes_list
    if not flag: # flag 1: encrypt, 0: decrypt
        iterative_index.reverse()
    for start_index, end_index in iterative_index:
        raw_array[start_index:end_index] = element_xor(raw_array[start_index:end_index],
                                                       random_array)
    return raw_array

def differential_fig(raw_img, random_img, encrypt_flag):
    o_h, o_w, o_c = raw_img.shape
    mid_img = random_img[0, :, :, :]
    output_figure = np.zeros((o_h, o_w, o_c), dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(o_c):
        e_raw_img = raw_img[:, :, i].flatten()
        e_random_img = mid_img[:, :, i].flatten()
        origin_size = e_raw_img.size
        random_size = e_random_img.size
        if origin_size > random_size:
            e_raw_img = sliding_window_differential(e_raw_img, e_random_img, origin_size, 
                                                    random_size, encrypt_flag)
        else:
            e_random_img = e_random_img[:origin_size]
            e_raw_img = element_xor(e_raw_img, e_random_img)
        output_figure[:, :, i] = e_raw_img.reshape(o_h, o_w)
    return output_figure
```

Could anyone explain the phenomenon?
Or give suggestion to improve the process.

Answer (score 0):

The `list.reverse` method creates a copy of the given list with the items in reverse order, and copying takes time proportional to the number items in the list. You can use the `reverse` function instead to generate the items in reverse order to avoid making a copy. There will still be overhead from calling the generator, but it will be much smaller than that of copying.

Change:

```
iterative_index.reverse()
```

to:

```
iterative_index = reverse(iteratie_index)
```